# Launch the legacy client as default

Tags: league-of-legends

I updated my client to the new one and I like it, but I'm encountering some performance issues.

It always takes long to choose the bans or the champion that I want to play, which sometimes makes it look like I'm AFK in the champion selection.

I know that I can launch the legacy client here:

[image]

Is there any way to put the legacy client as default? Or do I always need to launch this client first and then go to the old one?

Comment: Also try the new low spec mode. The legacy client option is likely not going to be around forever. Even now it is missing some of the newer features that the current client has like the sandbox mode.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [**this**](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/5dqkca/how_to_launch_legacy_client_by_default/) Reddit post (also in **[this](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/alpha-client-discussion/irEothGt-workaround-for-launching-the-legacy-client)** Boards post):

> 1. Make sure League of Legends or any of its processes aren't running.
> 2. Go to C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\System
> 3. Open user.cfg
> 4. Change leagueClientOptIn = yes to: leagueClientOptIn = no
> 5. Save user.cfg and close it
> 6. Enjoy the faster log-in process

Although there are some users who still have problems with this option, it seems to work for the majority of people

Comment: Didn't work for me...